# Serialize other fields in retrofit based on a field value

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am working on a json response with retrofit and it has a field named by type in price json object with 3 cases: free, static and dynamic.
in each case the response is like this:
1. static:

```
{
"status": 200,
"message": "Course Details Successful",
"data": {
    "id": 204,
    "title": "اصول حسابداری2",
    "price": {
        "type": "static",
        "value": {
            "price": "600000",
            "rebate": 0
        },
        "expire": "2018/01/18"
    }
}
}
```

2.dynamic:

```
{
"status": 200,
"message": "Course Details Successful",
"data": {
    "id": 18,
    "title": "دوره کامل و حرفه ای اکسل (50 ساعت)",
    "price": {
        "type": "dynamic",
        "value": {
            "2017-07-18 23:59:59": "165000",
            "2017-08-18 23:59:59": "125000"
        },
        "titles": [
            "دانشجویان دانشگاه تهران (داشبورد)",
            "سایر علاقه مندان (داشبورد)"
        ],
        "main_value": "165000",
        "max_discount": "80"
    }
}
}
```

3.free:

```
{
"status": 200,
"message": "Seminar Details Successful",
"data": {
    "id": 204,
    "title": "کنفرانس ملی برجام - بهمن 95",
    "price": {
        "type": "free",
        "value": "0",
        "expire": null
    }
}
}
```

What I want is to get those three responses and serialize other values according to the type value without changing main pojo. But I have no idea how to do that.I'm using retrofit for parsing data in my app.

Comment: you can serialize only the parent data and do the parsing manually.

Comment: @pastillas so how serialize price object as string because it cause problem and the response is going to onFailure function

Comment: you need to use a custom converter, which leads you to parse specific part of your json as intended. take a look at this blog : [handling dynamic json format with retrofit in android](http://huteri.me/2015/10/16/handling-dynamic-jsonapi-format-with-retrofit-in-android/)

Comment: @mohammadhoseinabedini hmm, I haven't tried this solution but I think it will work. instead of searializing on a String variable, serialize a JSONObject to capture also the subtree.

Comment: custom converter will solve your problem